# Is it possible to change the font color of a flexdashboard valuebox?

Tags: css, r, colors, fonts, flexdashboard

Is it possible to change the font color of a flexdashboard valuebox?
The default color is white. But I don't know how to change the color to black.

````
### Population

```{r}
Withtext <- dollar_format(prefix = "",suffix="",big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ".")
valueBox(Withtext(5112050), icon = "fa-user-alt",col="#D3D3D3")
````

Comment: `valueBox(Withtext(5112050), icon = "fa-user-alt",color="black")` doesn't work?

Comment: Strangely not. col/color changes only the background-color.

Comment: Can you make this post reproducible by including the libraries required and relevant data?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a CSS code chunk to the dashboard and style a valuebox.

````
```{css}

.value-output {
  color: red;
}

.caption {
  color: yellow;
}

```
````

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Muc9I.png)